# My <p> tag in my title section won't center align properly

Tags: html, css

The `<p>` tag won't center align properly and I am not sure why. Please can you check my code and see where I am going wrong.

You can see in the picture that the alignment is slightly off.

The CSS added is what I think related to the section. I did not code the below, just trying to edit.

```css
 #hero-area2 .contents {
    padding: 200px 0 130px;
  }
  
  #hero-area2 .contents h1 {
    color: rgb(38, 211, 125);
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  
  #hero-area2 .contents p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgb(38, 211, 125);
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #hero-area2 .contents .btn {
    margin: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

```html
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="contents text-center">
            <h1 class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Kuvumela Amandla</h1>
            <p class="lead  wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="400ms">Our Service Offering</p>
            <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-common wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms"
              data-wow-delay="400ms">CONTACT US</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="contents text-center">
        <h1 class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Kuvumela Amandla</h1>
        <p class="lead  wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="400ms">Our Service Offering</p>
        <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-common wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="400ms">CONTACT US</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Not properly aligned]

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I just noticed the className `'lead'` on the `<p>` tag. This may be a style class used by some framework/library like Bootstrap. Is it possible that removing that className will remove the extra "leading" space on the left? The resulting code would look like this: `<p class="wow fadeIn"`.

Comment: `p` is a block level element. Inorder to make the text inside `p` center add class `text-center` to `p`

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no problem in p tag .I guess ,you are using bootstrap and you took a column .col-md-10.And the column doesn't exits center. USE .col-md-10.offset-md-1 I think, it will work

Answer (score 0):

i didnt understand ur problem but i tried such css code  :
display: grid
align-items: center

```
justify-content: center
background-color: blue
height: 100px
width: 200px
```

sorry iv learned css since 1 month only

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #hero-area2 .contents {
    padding: 200px 0 130px;
  }
  
  #hero-area2 .contents h1 {
    color: rgb(38, 211, 125);
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  
  #hero-area2 .contents p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgb(38, 211, 125);
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-align: center;
  }
.kon{
       text-align: center;
}
  
  #hero-area2 .contents .btn {
    margin: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

```html
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="contents text-center">
            <h1 class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Kuvumela Amandla</h1>
            <p class="kon" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="400ms">Our Service Offering</p>
            <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-common wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms"
              data-wow-delay="400ms">CONTACT US</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dispay : flex;
```

**USE THIS on CSS, worked for me**

Answer (score -1):

**Here's my best guess to fix your problem**

I can't say for certain if this is your issue, but `<p>` tags often have some extra padding added to them which may result in a wonky placement on your web page.

Try removing the padding using css:

```css
p {
  padding: 0
}
```

or try adding inline styles to your p element:

```html
<p style='padding: 0'>
```

EDIT:

Another idea is that the className `lead` might be adding padding to the "leading edge" of the p element. Try removing that className from the `<p>` element, like so:

Before

`<p class="lead  wow fadeIn"`

After

`<p class="wow fadeIn"`

Comment: Using the padding nor taking out the className lead worked unfortunately.